# Displaying an image from database in list view using Android Studio

Tags: android

I am new to Android Studio. I used Retrofit for server request. I want to send an image in the database and want to show back in that same image. How can I do it?

Comment: How about Google researching?

Comment: Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). You are expected to have *researched your issue and made a good attempt to write the code yourself* before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a summary of what you have tried and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

1. Convert your image into byte array and apply it using db query

   ```
    public static byte[] getBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, stream);
        return stream.toByteArray();
    }
   ```
2. After getting byte array from db you should to convert it to image

   ```
    public static Bitmap getImage(byte[] image) {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
    }
   ```
3. Create class of you object and declare custom adapter of the list view:

   ```
    //your object's class
    public class Book {
        String mName;
        long mPrice;
        Bitmap mPhoto;
    }

    //custom adapter
    public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Book> {
        public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<Book> books) {
            super(context, 0, books);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            if(row == null) {
                // inflate row layout and assign to 'row'
            }
            final thisBook = getItem(position);
            final ImageView photo = row.findViewById(R.id.photo);
            photo.setImageBitmap(thisBook.mPhoto);

            return row;
        }
    }
   ```

Also try this [tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20200718180158/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/10/how-to-insert-image-data-to-sqlite.html)

Comment: I think this was downvoted because some people would like helpers to refrain from answering zero-effort questions. However, it looks very useful, so I will balance out the vote. If you can encourage question authors to do some research on very short questions in the future, that would be great!